# Clear TextField inside ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How onTap clear TextField in below example?

Note TextField  is positioned inside trailing in ListView

```
trailing: FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
  child: SizedBox(
    height:40, width:100,
    child: TextField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: _docData[index].quantity.toString()),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffix: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.clear,
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: could you tell where _docData come from?

Comment: @eamirho3ein      for (Map<String, dynamic> docData in responseJson) {
  _docData.add(ItemsData.fromJson(docData));
 }

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Create a list of `TextEditingController`

```
List<TextEditingController> controllers = List.empty(growable: true);
```

Then inside `ListView.builder`, create `TextEditingController` one by one and add it to controllers list.

Then assign to `TextField` and clear like this

```
child: TextField(
      controller: controllers[index],
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffix: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              controllers[index].clear();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.clear,
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

When we call the function:

```
 setState(() {
              
            });
```

The whole widget rebuilds hence your `TextEditingController` is initialized again so the text inside is reset to default which is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
Full Code

1)First Screen
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

2)Second Screen

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
State<MyCustomForm> createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  TextEditingController _controller =TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // question: delete textField inside the ListView
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value){
             _controller.text;
              },
              controller: _controller,
                   decoration:  InputDecoration(
                     hintText: 'Enter Name',
                     suffix: InkWell(
                       onTap: (){
                         _controller.clear();
                       },
                       child:Icon(Icons.clear),
                     )
                   ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).